# React js website inside a react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to build a website which has 3-4 pages. In later stage I want to build an app for the same. i.e I want to open the website in react native app. I want to do this to avoid app updates. 
I will add/remove components in website so that it will reflect in the app without any update. 
what is the best approach for this? 
Any code samples or blogs ?

Comment: the only possible way I see here is, you can create a complete website, deploy it to a url and use it inside webview using react-native-webview library.

Comment: Yes. That would work. is there any sample code for that ? and will apple store accept such apps?

Comment: Also, read that, Apple store will not approve the apps if its webview without native components. anyone experienced this? @AmmarTariq

Comment: Appstore will not allow any application that has only basic functionality, speaking from my personal experience, appstore has rejected my ecommerce app with basic cart and checkout options, saying it is not suitable to be an app, how I tricked them including notifications to my project and adding basic notification handling.